# Windows 11 22H2 has completely obliterated any audio output

Tags: audio, windows-11

I have an ITX B550 that just stopped outputting audio, any audio. I’ve tried everything in the OS to troubleshoot, including drivers. I’ve changed GPUs to make sure it isn’t that as well as testing an assortment of drivers around it. I’m just stumped TBH. Bios has been updated and CMOS cleared. The OS shows no trouble or indications of hardware failure, in fact all OS indicators show functional sound, but nothing. Initially System sounds worked and no application sounds, now it is just everything. I've rolled back and uninstalled updates, installed audio drivers from mobo mfg site, no effect. All output devices have been checked, each one disabled one by one in device manager, no effect. I know it isn't a hardware issue since I've booted from USB w/ Ubuntu and audio works perfectly.

Devices I've tried in Win11

- front panel audio jack
- usb headphones
- display port out
- bluetooth earbuds

Windows configurations I've tried

- Boot in safe mode
- Boot ignoring signed drivers
- used generic audio drivers
- device specific drivers
- created new profiles and problem persists
- Rolled back Audio drivers
- uninstalled KBs and performed rollbacks
- downloaded specific cab files from msoft
- used DDU to clear audio and GPU drivers

Unusual anomalies that may be related

- This was a Win10 to Win11 upgrade
- This and another AMD machine cannot RDP into a 2012R2
- Even though numlock on boot is on in the BIOS it isn't always functional on boot

Comment: Do you have hardware diagnostics for your machine? I would run these. It is not an endemic Windows 22H2 issue.  I have 3 22H2 or better machines

Comment: It isn't the hardware.  If I boot with Linux Ubuntu, audio outputs perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://appuals.com/audio-not-working-22h2-update-on-windows-11/) - note, that's the first result when using a search engine for the phrase "windows 22H2 audio issue"

Comment: t isn't the hardware. If I boot with Linux Ubuntu, audio outputs perfectly.    .... It is not a Windows issue.   Back up and reinstall Windows 11. Test audio before installing any software of your own.

Comment: @JaromandaX I actually didn't see the search result for the one you linked, but tried it all and nothing worked.  However, it did point out to me that I do not have the Audio Input and Outputs tab at the top of device manager, which is critical.  Under "All Sound Devices" I've found that audio output devices are duplicated and triplicated, but no way of deleting devices.